# Time Machine won't sync after moving backup to new destination

Tags: backup, time-machine, catalina, nas

I migrated from a custom-built Ubuntu machine to a QNAP TS-431 and therefore archived the Time Machine `.backupbundle` directory of my MacBook to a tarball and moved it to a network share on the NAS which I set up as described in the [QNAP guide](https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/using-time-machine-to-back-up-macs-to-a-qnap-nas-via-smb-3/). However, even after successfully mounting the share, my MacBook won't backup to the new destination, failing quietly without any error message. After the "Preparing backup..." phase, the Time Machine settings dialog just states "Oldest backup: None" and "Latest backup: None".

Is it possible to get my old backup working again or is it likely to be broken?

Comment: If you to to Time Machine > Preferences > Select Disk, do you see the volume you moved it to?

Comment: Yes, the volume is selected and I can even force start the backup. The dialog shows "Preparing backup..." and stops after a few minutes.

Comment: Hmm. You may want to check out [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221996/time-machine-move-backup-from-local-disk-to-network-volume-wrong-case-sensiti).