# Can't empty trash of removable HD

Tags: macos, external-disk, trash

I can't empty the trash of my removable drive. At first it appears to empty it correctly (no error message, the sound is played), but the folder in question stays there.

I tried:

```
jan@MacBook-Pro /Volumes/JD 2 $ sudo rm -rf .Trashes/
```

which gives errors like the following:

```
rm: .Trashes//501: Directory not empty
rm: .Trashes/: Directory not empty
```

Anyways, I narrowed it down to a `.svn` file that can't be deleted:

```
root@MacBook-Pro /Volumes/JD 2/.Trashes/501/CD_10.2009/devel/funghos $ ls -altr .svn
-rwxrwxrwx  1 _unknown  _unknown  690 Oct 21  2009 .svn
root@MacBook-Pro /Volumes/JD 2/.Trashes/501/CD_10.2009/devel/funghos $ rm -f .svn
root@MacBook-Pro /Volumes/JD 2/.Trashes/501/CD_10.2009/devel/funghos $ ls -altr .svn
-rwxrwxrwx  1 _unknown  _unknown  690 Oct 21  2009 .svn
```

As you can see, no error appears, but the file doesn't get deleted. Huh?

Comment: Wow.  That file has been around for a while!

Comment: Did you try `sudo rm -f .svn` in the second step yet?

Comment: @patrix: I run it as root.

Comment: Do you get an error message if you omit the `-f` option?

Comment: @patrix: just tried, and no, it just doesn't say/do anything.

Comment: That's strange indeed?!

Comment: @patrix: yea, even more strange is that a Windows machine was able to delete it just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue by deleting the file on a Windows machine. Must be a bug in OS X or something?

Comment: not a bug — it appears none of the answers here are 100% correct, which is obviously why you resorted to using this route.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `MNT_IGNORE_OWNERSHIP` flag being set for the drive when mounted. The `unknown` user and group are exactly what show up when root views files on a drive for which permissions are ignored.  When a user views the permissions, the files will show up as their own.  I'm surprised you can't delete the `.svn` file from your own account (not root)

Please see this [Ask Different Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53165/23703) for more direction.  Basically, you'll need to uncheck the "Ignore ownership on this volume" checkbox from an inspector on the drive info.

If you can't delete it from your user account, try setting yourself as the file owner with the ignore flag unset.

Comment: Just tried, but there's no box for "Ignore ownership on this volume" -- [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/77YZ5.png)

Comment: Ah, NTFS. OS X doesn't have native write support for NTFS, maybe the FUSE driver has some problems. Can you attach the drive to a Windows box?

Comment: @patrix: Yes it worked on a Windows box, I posted it as an answer but can't accept yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instruction:

1- Drag the file from your Trash bin to the Desktop.
2- Launch a Terminal
3- Type

```
cd ~/.Trash && sudo rm -rf [your file path on the desktop]
```

4- Then press enter and enter your password

Comment: Eh, why do you change into `~/.Trash` before running sudo?

Comment: Dragging the file to the desktop = copying it to the desktop and deleting it in the old place, which doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

- Connect your removable HD to a win
- Show hidden files (folder option/ uncheck hidden files)
- Try to delete .Trash folder in the root of the usb drive
- If errors, use [unlocker](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to delete
- Plug in your mac again, you will see the annoying files/folders in Trash disappeared

cheers

Answer (score -1):

If you can locate the file in Finder, can bring up the info pane (cmd-i) on that file and check its not locked or has incorrect permissions?